# Getting DRY with Python Conditionals and Django returns

Tags: python, django, dry

What I'm about to share is a common pattern in my projects. Some cases are longer than others but the pattern is more or less the same and I'm wondering how I can be more DRY.

```
if status == 'ACTIVE' and p.result != "0":

    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 
        _('Active Message... bla bla bla'))

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('billing_update'))

if status == 'TOO MANY FAILURES':

    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 
        _('Failed. Foooobarrrrr'))

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('billing_update'))

if status == 'DEACTIVATED BY MERCHANT':

    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 
        _('Deactivated derpa derp'))

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('billing_update'))
```

The only thing that is happening here is setting a message based on status. Theres got to be a way to called the return only once and maybe even tighten up the conditional.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Could it be something in the line of:

*lib module*

```
def add_error_message(request, status, result=0):
    if status == 'ACTIVE' and not result:
        msg = 'Active Message... bla bla bla'
    elif status == 'TOO MANY FAILURES':
        msg = 'Failed. Foooobarrrrr'
    elif status == 'DEACTIVATED BY MERCHANT':
        msg = 'Deactivated derpa derp'
    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, _(msg))
```

Wouldn't it be for the 'p.result' condition, a dictionary would have been much better:

```
MESSAGES = {
    'ACTIVE': 'Active Message... bla bla bla',
    'TOO MANY FAILURES': 'Failed. Foooobarrrrr',
    'DEACTIVATED BY MERCHANT': 'Deactivated derpa derp',
}
def add_error_message(request, status):
    try:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, _(MESSAGES[status]))
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

*view module*

```
from lib import add_error_message

def your_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...
    add_error_message(request, status, p.result if p else 0)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('billing_update'))
```

Comment: I think I like this and it also helps demonstrate that I can take a lot of other portions of repeated code and apply the same. Is ``lib.py`` a common pattern amongst django projects? I've never built my views outside of.... views.py ;)

Comment: You are free to modularize our code anyhow you like. That function can live in the same views.py module if it is not needed anywhere else. The whole point of DRY is that, factor out common code into functions and put them somewhere accessible. Some people use `lib.py` some `utils.py`, some which like Ruby on Rails could think about using `helpers.py`. Just be coherent inside your own project, and document your code.

Comment: This doesn't really help him not repeat himself -- the duplication of `messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, _())` is still there. This is just greater modularization --- it could just be done by putting it into a method. And, if it's only used from `views.py`, it doesn't necessarily belong semantically in another module.

Comment: @agf you are right, I forgot to un-repeat that piece, it was on my mind but not on my fingers. Anyway I edited to be much more DRY now. Thanks.

Comment: @agf the module thing is explained in another comment. It's clear that Flowpoke wasn't aware of the possibility of putting code in different modules, so now it's up to him to use this "feature" if necessary.

Comment: I think you made a couple of errors -- shouldn't it be `not result` in your first version, and you didn't check `result` at all in the second version

Comment: @agf, eagle-eye! You are right for the first. I'll correct. For the second example, it's introduced by the sentence "Wouldn't it be for the 'p.result' condition, a dictionary would have been much better" so it's not a solution, rather a suggestion on trying to refactor the code in a way that with just a dictionary is enough.

Comment: @saviero Ahh, I got it. That's why I moved status inside my version; so no other changes were necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your last return is conditional, and guess based on my own similar code that if neither of the checks triggers, you want to go on and return something else, maybe not even a redirect ...

Here's how I think I would do it:

```
def checkForMessage():
    if status == 'ACTIVE' and p.result != "0":
        return 'Active Message... bla bla bla'
    if status == 'TOO MANY FAILURES':
        return 'Failed. Foooobarrrrr'
    if status == 'DEACTIVATED BY MERCHANT':
        return 'Deactivated derpa derp'
    return None

msg = checkForMessage()
if msg:
    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, _(msg))

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('billing_update'))

// ... go on and do some other stuff ...
return direct_to_template('some/template.html', {some: stuff})
```

Note that the function checkForMessage is defined inside the view function, so we don't have to pass everything involved in a test as a parameter to it (in case the tets are many and varied, if they just require a status and some "p" variable, it can just as well be declared outside the view function and take those parameters).

The main point is that the "fall through" alternative where we don't want to add any message at all can be handled by returning None in the check method and checking for the existence of a message in the view method.

Comment: As if closures were easy and safe for a beginner programmer... ;)

Comment: Closures certainly have their complexities, but I don't think we should avoid a simple function in a function just because the language feature that implements it can be used in other ways which are very hard to comprehend.  :-)

Comment: Anyway, the main point here was not weather to pass those parameters or not, but that the checkForMessage method may return None, and we can use a secondary check for that to only add the message if there was a message to add, as I guessed that was the reason the message strings was not just put in a variable and added after all the checks.

Comment: I have seen lots of good-to-very-good programmers suffer for the scope syndrome and its sister the UnboundLocalError-itis :)

Comment: I added some more text to specify that the scoping is entirely optional.  However, as long as you don't pass a handle to the method out of the scope where it was created or something like that, I still don't think declaring it locally and having access to the outer method scope in the inner method is problematic.